# Lightswitch 2013 - Show Connection Info

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, lightswitch-2013

I'm just about to deploy my first LS2013 app (Desktop only). I have a dev and live SQL Db (external DB's only), so the connection string changes depending on which server I want to connect to

I'd ideally like a way for the user to be able to choose dev or live   that set the connection string. i don't think that's possible. Regardless of that, i'd like to be able to indicate somewhere (ideally menu bar, but if not in a splash screen) the name of the SQL server they are connected to.

Anyone know how to get some details of the current connection in C#?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a simple WCF RIA Service that returns a simple DTO with the environment data that you want. On the server you have access to 'WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings' and plenty other information. The MSDN docs on this are here:
[Guidelines for creating WCF RIA Service for LightSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589479.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had seen that. I have no experience with WCF/RIA and there seem to be a lot of changes required to implement FILESTREAM support: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx. Seems an awful lot of work to get connection info

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of LightSwitch included in VS2013 update 2 has support to dynamically change the connection string based on the user or any other criteria that you choose like a web.config setting.

Unfortunately this information is still undocumented and the LightSwitch team will do a blog post about this in the near future, so keep a look out on the LightSwitch MSDN website. You could also search the LightSwitch MSDN forum for the post where this new capability was announced in recent weeks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a kludge but you could have a table in each database called, say, Configuration, with a couple of columns: AttributeName and AttributeValue.

Your dev table could have a row with SQLServerName and DevBox1
Your live table would have SQLServerName and LiveBox1

Then you can just create a query to pull back the AttributeValue when AttributeName = "SQLServerName".